# How to return relationships in a custom un-typed dataservice provider

Tags: c#, .net, dataservice

I have a custom .Net DataService and can't figure out how to return the data for relationships.

The data base has 2 tables (Customer, Address). A Customer can have multiple addresses, but each address can only have on customer.

I'm using `Dictionary<string,object>` as my data type.

My question, for the following 2 urls how do i return the data.

http://localhost/DataService/Customer(1)/Address

http://localhost/DataService/Address(1)/Customer

For the none relational queries I return a `List<Dictionary<string,object>>`

So I imagined for the relation I should just populate the element with a either a `Dictionary<string,object>` for the single ones and a `List<Dictionary<string,object>>` for many relationships.

```
customer["Address"] = new List<Dictionary<string,object>>();

address["Customer"] = new Dictionary<string,object>();
```

But this just gives me a `NullRefferenceException`

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you manage serialization of your Customer and Address objects? Are the properties you're using public? Often, null reference exceptions from data services come from underlying private data not being returned from a call because they're inaccessible or unserializable, so they get quietly ignored on deserialization.